# Add coordinates to form in leaflet popup

Tags: database, mongoose, leaflet, maps, schema

We are trying add the latlng coodinates to our form input that is inside a leaflet popup. We have tried inline scripts and cant seem to get it to work.

```
function onMapClick(e) {

let userMarkers = [];
var marker = L.marker(e.latlng, {
  icon: theIcon,
  draggable: true
}).addTo(map).bindPopup("<form method='POST' action='/spotForm'> <div 
class='form-group'><label for='spotName'>Name</label><input 
type='text'class='form-control' id='spotName' placeholder='Name this 
spot!' name='spotName'></div><button type='submit' class='btn btn-
primary'>Add Spot Data</button></form>");
userMarkers.push(e.latlng);
console.log(userMarkers, "hi");



  }
  map.on('click', onMapClick);
  L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

Comment: You mean you let user place a Marker on your map an drag it to change its position. And it has a popup which form input values should be updated whenever the Marker has been moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Add id in the form which in present in the popup `<form
>   id="popup-form" method='POST' action='/spotForm'> </form>`

Now add **`popupopen`** event on map

```
 map.on('popupopen',function(e){
    var latLng = e["popup"]._latlng;
    var form = document.querySelector('#popup-form')
    form['spotName'].value = latLng['lat'] + ', ' +latLng['lng'];
});
```

Try this hope this will help you!

Comment: T H A N K Y O U ! !  !

Answer (score 0):

This works great! But now we need to get into a number.
Below is our schema to return coords from our leaflet map.

```
 //Schema
 name: {
 type: String,
 required: true,
 trim: true
 },
 properties:{

 },
 coordinates: [Number]
,
email: {
type: String,
unique: true,
required: true,
trim: true
},
```

This is code to returns coords on click to our form. But its not returning as a number but are returning as a string. How can we make the input be a number in our form?. We tried several things but none worked.

```
map.on('click', onMapClick);
  L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
  map.on('popupopen', function (e) {
    var latLng = e["popup"]._latlng;
    var form = document.querySelector('#popupForm');
    form['coordinates'].value = latLng['lat'] + ', ' + latLng['lng'];
```